# Azure Web App file missing on existing file

Tags: unity-container, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

We have two environments on Azure (Same site, same config etc...) All deployment was scripted over ARM Json files and deployment by VSTS.

When I hit the first environment, everything is ok.

But on the other environment, I caught exception. After investigation, it seems Azure does not see my unity config files (XML files in UTF-8). When I open all my files via (App Service Editor (Preview)) Note: I only set a space on the file for update only. After that my web app run well.

At each deployment, I need to go via Azure Portal to edit my Unity.config files to fix my WebApp.

Anyone have an idea about it? And why my first site with the same file, config, deployment working well, but not the second one?

Comment: instead of editing the file, what happens if you stop and start the site? does that solve the issue?

Comment: After investigation we found nothing. We opened ticket issue on Ms Azure but no concrete response to our question. Workaround we duplicate the Unity config into a node in the web.config file, and waiting for a correction...

Answer (score 1):

> it seems Azure does not see my unity config files (XML files in UTF-8).

Please double check whether the encoding of your config file is UTF-8 before deploying it. You could take following steps to check it.

1. Open your config file using Notepad.

[image]

2. After clicked File->Save As..., you will see the current encoding of your config file. If the current encoding is not UTF-8, please change the encoding to UTF-8 and save the file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the cue, but this solution not worked :-(